Get Heath status of paloaltonetworks.cloudngfw/firewalls in azure
Tried  searching but could find answer so posting here for help.
I want to get the " Heath status " of paloaltonetworks.cloudngfw/firewalls  which is SAAS based firewall in azure ..
I have tried  powershell to get the resouce but all i can see is the "provisioningState" under resouce properties..
how can i get the "heath status" which is "healthy "  using powershell or bash .. if there is any other way to query the same ..please let me know ..



If you click on "Json View" on the top-right corner and search for health or status are you able to find anything?

Hi @RuiJarimba : checked the JSON output , no key with heath or status ..nothing in output which says "healthy"

any help on this post team ? ..
